# jQuery insertBefore on each instance unexpected behaviour

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of div's with the class 'row', containing two divs 'image' and 'description'

I'm trying to make 'description' insert before 'image' in all instances.

I tried the following code which makes logical sense to me, but the outcome is very unexpected as you can see in the fiddle.

```
$('.row').each(function(){ //Select each row

    $('.description',this).insertBefore('.image',this);
    // For this row, put this description before this image

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/ott5tx06/

HTML

```
<div class="section-products">
<div class="row">
    <div class="image">
        image row 1
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        description row 1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="image">
        image row 2
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        description row 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="image">
        image row 3
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        description row 3
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.row div{
    width:45%;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}
.image{
    background-color:red;
}
.description{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to order them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insertBefore` needs an element as its argument.

http://jsfiddle.net/ott5tx06/4/

```
$('.row').each(function(){ //Select each row

    $('.description',this).insertBefore($('.image',this));
    // For this row, put this description before this image

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting jQuery object selector

```
$('.description',this).insertBefore($(".image", this));
```

for string selector

```
'.image',this
```

which does not process `context` parameter `this` as `.row`

http://jsfiddle.net/ott5tx06/5/

alternatively using `.prependTo()`

```
$('.row').each(function(){ //Select each row   
    $('.description',this).prependTo(this);
    // For this row, put this description before this image    
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ott5tx06/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the order of the div elements, try this:

```
$('.row').each(function(){ //Select each row

    $('.description',this).insertBefore($('.image',this));
    // For this row, put this description before this image

});
```

`insertBefore()` puts the elements in the set before the target, but you need an actual target - you can't pass a string & separate context as you do when constructing a jQuery object.